# what is standard acoustic volume

Tags: audio, sound, acoustics, measurement

In Audio Experts book, it's given as

> Sound pressure meters must be calibrated at factory to a standard acoustic volume.

So what doth this `standard acoustic volume` means?

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is **94 dB** of Sound Pressure Level, where 0 dB is 20 µPa of acoustic pressure. This is the SPL you will find in most of the acoustic calibrators for measurement microphones.